# Display an array with string list vertically knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I got `self.PatrolList = ko.observableArray()` which contains:

```
//value
0: {DateAdd: 'Tuesday, 01 November 2022', sessionList: Array(2)}
1: {DateAdd: 'Wednesday, 02 November 2022', sessionList: Array(4)}

//sessionList value
Array(2)
0: "Patrol_011122168"
1: "Patrol_011122256"
```

Now, I want to display them. The problem is `sessionList` value displaying in a string:

View:

```
<div class="overflow-auto body-overflow" data-bind="foreach:PatrolList">
    <div class="timeline-date" data-bind="text: DateAdd"><i class="fa fa-calendar text-success"></i></div>
        <ul>
           <li class="timeline-content" data-bind="text: sessionList"></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

[image]

How do I split them by `(,)` and display vertically. What I want to achieve :

```
Tuesday, 01 November 2022
 -Patrol_011122168
 -Patrol_011122256
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use another loop on `ul`, you can use `$data` to get the current value.

```js
class ViewModel {
  sessionList = [
    "Patrol_011122168",
    "Patrol_011122256",
  ]
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: sessionList">
  <li class="timeline-content" data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's the similar solutions I got after posting this question. Still thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.
I just have to tweak my view a little bit:

```
<div class="overflow-auto body-overflow" data-bind="foreach:PatrolList">
     <div class="timeline-date" data-bind="text: DateAdd"><i class="fa fa-calendar text-success"></i> 28 Dec</div>
                    <ul data-bind="foreach: $data.sessionList">
                        <li class="timeline-content" data-bind="text: $data"></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

Funnily, I got the solution seconds after posting this questions.